# Lua (Roblox) how to call something from Localscript

Tags: lua, roblox

Server Script has this piece of code in it. It occurs when a Player touches a brick...

```
game.workspace.CurrentCamera.CameraSubject = clone.Head
```

This piece of code works fine if run inside of Roblox studio. but when run from the roblox servers, does not work.

I understand why it does not work, because Current Camera must be changed from a Local script.. MY problem is that I can not find a way to call a Localscript from a Server script ...

I tried creating a function in a local script

```
function changeCameraSubj(newSubj)
    game.workspace.CurrentCamera.CameraSubject = clone.Head
end
```

but can not seem to call a LocalScript function directly form a server script ...

so my question is, what is the best way to call a function that must be performed in a LocalScript from a Server Script? I hav tried many vairations on the above, but nothing seems to communicate properly . 
Common sense would tell me that I need to create a custom server event that the local script can listen for, but I can not seem to find any way for that to work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I can't personally think of any reason why you would need to do this through a ServerScript; if possible, I'd recommend simply doing this through a LocalScript.

That said, if you must use a ServerScript for this, have your local code in a LocalScript, and trigger it on your ServerScript through a [RemoteEvent](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/RemoteEvent). If you need a tutorial, there's a very informative guide [here](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Remote_Events_and_Functions).

Comment: thank you for the reply ... player does something within the server script which requires the camera subj changes... but camera subj can only be changed in a local script. so i need to send a remote event to the client. I had looked before at the page you referenced, and I notce that in every example they assume the event will always occur immediately when the player is added, and I have never found a stripped down example of creating an event that can occur within the actual gameplay (not only when the player is added)

Comment: could you possibly give me an example of the minimum calls needed in both scripts in order for them both to communicate properly .. eg server script code needed to create the event .. and localscript code needed to listen for the event .. I can not easily sort through all the extra code in their example to know specifically what is required for the event on both scripts, and what is just extra filler for that specific case

Comment: Second link is broken